# Open protected Workbook in background when it is already open by other person - VB.Net

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have a issue.
My code opens protected workbook in background - and it works fine, no issue
But then workbook is already open by other user password window pops up - how to change that so user won't be able to see that password window?
I add on error goto errhandler which contains that workbook is already open - it works fine when item is no protected, but with password this password window pops up.

Thank You in advance

```
on error goto errhan
Workbooks.Open Filename:= "C:\johndoe.xls", Password:="Password"
exit sub

errhan
messagebox.show("File is already open")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's quite hard to understand your question. Is this summary correct: when you open a password protected workbook your code works fine, but when you open a password protected workbook that another user has open, it asks for the password?

Comment: yes - but not me but application. Application opens workbook

Comment: Are you sure it's asking for the password and not just warning that it's already opened? What .NET library are you using to interface with Excel?

Comment: No. Excel window pops up to type password to Read-only mode (only if workbook is already open)
I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open?view=excel-pia - there's various different parameters you can supply to `Open` which alter the behaviour. E.g. `IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended`, `ReadOnly`, `Notify`.

Comment: None of that resolve my issue with popping password window from excel

Answer (score 0):

I've been unable to reproduce your exact issue. Using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` if I try to open a password protected workbook that is already open, I get the following message:

[image: read-only messagebox]

This is how I'm opening the file:

```vb
wb = wbs.Open(Filename:=Location, Password:="password", Notify:=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
```

This is what I would expect, but you're saying isn't happening.

As a side note, I don't think the `Notify` property works as expected; even with `Notify:=False` it still raises the notification.

The main issue you've got is the when using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` all of the file opening logic is handled by the `Excel.Application` instance rather than your application. For example, if you don't provide a password it will ask for one, rather than throwing an exception. This is useful in some cases, but for automating tasks it's a bit annoying as without any feedback you can't write proper logic control.

I would recommend you look into using something like [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) to handle your Excel file reading/writing. Not only is it less resource intensive (you don't have to spin up an Excel application instance) it also throws exceptions when the file needs a password, or when it's being used by another user, which allows you to handle all these different situations in your application and minimalise the amount of user interaction that's required.